# Membership.GetUser() returns null when using OpenId login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I'm working in a small ASP.net MVC4 web app, and using the external login options, for allowing my users to log on with their Google account.

For linking their profile with their data, I need a unique identifier, and using the username didn't looked like a safe choice.

I've been looking in several places and the best way to get a user id is Membership.GetUser(). This works for local created users, but not for external ones, returning null.

How can I archive this? Have anyone find a workaround for this issue?

The information about OpenId and Oauth is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/15/oauth-openid-support-for-webforms-mvc-and-webpages.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SimpleMembership you can use the WebSecurity class's .CurrentUserId property. That should work for both local accounts and OAuth accounts.